# What is the admin url in an App Engine application?

Tags: google-app-engine

I once used a page automatically created by App Engine SDK to view the database contents and other info, but I lost the URL. Do you know it? Does it work in production?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The development console url is http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/.

It does not work in production, but you can use GAE's dashboard in this case: https://appengine.google.com/.

Dev server's documentation is available [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver.html).

Answer (score 3):

It's http://appengine.google.com/ if you're not using Google Apps.

Otherwise, it's `http://appengine.google.com/a/<your-domain>`

There is a section on Data there that includes the Datastore viewer, indexes, etc..

Answer (score 1):

In case you found this answer and you're using [App Engine SDK 1.7.6](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver) or higher, the default URL has changed from `localhost:8080/_ah/admin` to `localhost:8000`.